# Use component with Taiwlind from outside of NextJS root directory?

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

Im using a React component which has Tailwind CSS classes in my NextJS app, but the component resides outside of the project root.

To allow NextJS to import the component I added this to next.config.js:

```
const nextConfig = {
  experimental: {
    externalDir: true,
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

And in my tailwind.config.js I add `OTHER-FOLDER` to the content array:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./src/pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "../OTHER-FOLDER/src/*.tsx",
  ],
```

The component is loaded and works perfectly except that the Tailwind styles are missing.

Comment: Take a look at how this was achieved using `path`. https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/discussions/7717#discussioncomment-3507789